# Differentiability question

Tags: calculus, limits

Investigate differentiability of:
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} &\mbox{if } x^2+y^2>0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x^2+y^2. \end{cases}  $$
definition of differentiability i have to know is:

Function is differentiable if there exists a linear transformation $L(h)$ such that:
$$h\in \mathbb{R}^k, \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-L(h)}{||h||}$$
I know that first i have to calculate all partial derivatives but value at (0,0) gives 1 for x derivative and -1 for y derivative this would imply that $L(h)=h_1-h_2$ but this does not result in final limit from the definition to be equal to zero as it should be. How to solve that?

Comment: How is $n$ in $f(n)$ on the left-hand side related to $x, y$ on the right-hand side? And what does $\bmod 2$ mean in this context?

Comment: mod 2 was my mistake

Comment: $f(n)$ on the lhs still makes no sense. Do you mean $f(x, y)$ ?

Comment: yes this as well was a typo

Comment: @Anonymous The function is the same, but the question is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you convert it in to polar co-ordinate

Put $x=rcos(θ)$ and $y=rsin(θ)$

then on simplification you will get

$ f(r,θ)=\frac{r^2}{4}sin(4θ) $now it will be very easy to differentiate now

Answer (score 1):

The function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}),$ hence is differentiable there. So the only problem point is $(0,0).$ Now $f=0$ on the $x$ and $y$ axes, hence the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ are both $0.$ It's clear then that if $Df(0,0)$ exists, it is the $0$ transformation. So what we want is

$$f(x,y) = f(0,0) +Df(0,0)(x,y) + o((x^2+y^2)^{1/2}) = o((x^2+y^2)^{1/2}).$$

Try to show this.